# How to fetch right date value in Bs Datepicker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I saved a value in database using Bs Datepicker. But when I'm fetching date in angular it displays -1 date (e.g if date is 30/05/2020 then it shows 29/05/2020). I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgprbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of what I'm doing.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue like this because my database and api was on server (front-end and api was not in same countries). the problem is **time zone** you need to send date to server with timezone and save in databese. while showing date to your front-end application you need to reconvert this date to local timezone. you can use [moment js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment) to convert date formats in angular.

the other way is you can recieve date as string from front-end application to api. then convert it to Datetime and save to database. it will save date as it as you send. but i will not prefer this because you will lose timezone...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one also in your .ts:

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
```

In you .ts function before sending to db:

```
const dateTemp = new Date(yourPickedDate);
const finalDate = this.datepipe.transform(dateTemp, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Now, send finalDate to db.